# fail2ban - documentation of action variables?

Tags: fail2ban

I'm using fail2ban on my server and generating a report out of the bans.
I couldn't find a documentation about all the possible variables in the actions, anyone got a source?

i.e. I could use `<failures>` to indicate the number of failed attempts. Is there a way to retrieve the issued bantime as well? (I'm using increasing bantimes, so It would be interesting if an ip is currently beeing banned for 1 min (first fail) or 1 day (multiple fails)

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find a documentation about all the possible variables in the actions, anyone got a source?

Some of them are documented (see [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/fail2ban/jail.conf.5.en.html#Action_Tags), I know it still lacks many), another are not yet, for the whole list you can check the [source code](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/8c4d02403b4768fb1a76372a7a462fc903c2711e/fail2ban/server/actions.py#L380-L400). This list is valid for 0.11.3(dev) and it can grow in future versions or miss some of them in previous versions, so check against your version, you can select the branch-tag (e. g. 0.11.1) above in the page.

To obtain in the action some parameters the filter can capture from matched message you could use `<F-*>` tags, see [fail2ban/#1935, comment](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1935#issuecomment-339113985) for usage example.

> Is there a way to retrieve the issued bantime as well?

This is a bit more complex - although tag `<bantime>` (as well as `<bancount>`) is available in actions, the issue is that prolongation is executed asynchronous to the `actionban`, that on the other hand will be executed as soon as possible (in order to ban the intruder ASAP), so you may get initial `bantime` which is specified in jail for some tickets if they are not yet prolonged when `actionban` started.
But there is another parameter you can set to obtain prolonged values only - `actionprolong`, which is invoked after `actionban` only for tickets getting increased `bantime`.

```
actionprolong = echo "<name>: ban for <ip> prolonged, bantime: <bantime>, banned: <bancount> times" >> /tmp/banned.log
```